# Grouping a set of log entries into visits, in SQL, based on time since last entry

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite, group-by, common-table-expression

I have a table of log entries with an id, timestamp, source_ip (for the IP address) and some other data. I want to group this into "visits", where a visit is all log entries from one IP address where there were < X seconds since last log entry. i.e. for every log entry in a visit, there must be at least one other entry in that visit whose timstamp was < X seconds before or after this one.

If X = 10 minutes IP A has the following requests: 12:00, 12:05, 12:11, 12:40, 12:42, 12:50, 12:52, 14:01, then there are 3 visit groups: [12:00, 12:05, 12:11], [12:40, 12:42, 12:50, 12:52], [14:01].

I would like to do this entirely in SQL, but I'm not sure how. I'm guessing it a form of group by, perhaps with Common Table Expressions (WITH clause)? Can anyone tell me how to generate this? I'd know how to do it in Python (say), but I'd like to have it done in SQL

I'm currently trying this with SQLite 3, but I'm willing to change to PostgreSQL (even to postgresql 9.5).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Postgres.  I wouldn't recommend SQLite, because it does not support window/analytic functions.

You can find where a group begins using `lag()` and some date arithmetic.  Then you can do a cumulative sum on this information to identify each group:

```
select l.*,
       sum(case when prev_ts + interval '10 minute' > timestamp then 0
                else 1
           end) over (partition by ip order by timestamp) as groupid
from (select l.*, 
             lag(timestamp) over (partition by ip order by timestamp) as prev_ts
      from logs l
     ) l;
```